# I want to edit pdf using pdf-lib in NodeJs with Arabic texts

Tags: node.js

I encounter a lot of issues when I wanted to use pdf-lib to edit an existing pdf and to add some texts in specific positions (x,y) , and the interesting part here is that texts should be in Arabic When using English texts , editing is done perfectly. But when trying Arabic texts , the following winansi error popped up: Error: WinAnsi cannot encode "م" (0x0645)

I also tried to use custom font , using fontkit , but I encountered a lot of error such as : PDFDocument.embedFont was a custom font, but no fontkit instance was found. You must register a fontkit instance with PDFDocument.registerFontkit(...) before embedding custom fonts.

I have following what is inside official pdf-lib github usage , but still is not working

Last error that I encounter when I tried to pass utf-8 when reading the existing file , and when saving the modified file , is :

Failed to parse PDF document (line:108 col:1144 offset=9484): No PDF header found

Does anyone have a PoC controller/function in NodeJs to edit an existing PDF with adding texts in Arabic ?

Thanks a lot

Tried a lot of attempts , and Im expecting to have modified pdf output with arabic texts added

Comment: Fontkit is already installed, and I will share the code

Comment: see my answer down, if you have any idea how to support me 
by the way , we are talking about pdf-lib and pdf-lib/fontkit , and not pdfkit

Answer (score 0):

solved my issue about these errors
here is my code:

```
const { PDFDocument, rgb} = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const fontkit = require('@pdf-lib/fontkit');


genrateCard = async (req, res) => {
    const inputPath = './poc.pdf'; // Path to existing PDF
    const outputPath = './modified.pdf'; // Path to output modified PDF
    const fontPath = './fonts/Amiri-Regular.ttf'; // Path to output modified PDF    

    //Nom et position
    const nom = req.body.nomPrenom; // Text to be added
    const xNom = 220 - nom.length; // X-coordinate
    const yNom = 730; // Y-coordinate

        //Get an existing pdf file to edit 
        const existingPdfBytes = await fs.readFile(inputPath);
        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
    
       //Add font kit to the project
        pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
    
       // Get all pages of the pdf document 
        const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
    
        // Select the page to working on
        const firstPage = pages[0];
    
        // Here it's where you start to add your custom using file system.
        const customFont1 = await fs.readFile(fontPath);

    
        // Add the font file content into the doc
        const cusFont1 = await pdfDoc.embedFont(customFont1);    
    
        // Now you can draw your text on your document, just an exemple ...
        firstPage.drawText(nom, {
            x: xNom,
            y: yNom,
            size: 10,
            font: cusFont1,
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0),
        });
    
       // Like in the official documentation, this is you final document
        const modifiedpdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    
        try {
            fs.writeFile(outputPath, modifiedpdfBytes);
            return res.json({
                "result": true,
                "response": {src: 'PDF GENERATED'}
            })
        } catch (e) {
            return res.json({
                "result": false,
                "response": {error: e}
            })
        }
}

module.exports = { genrateCard }
```

seems like Amiri font is bad for arabic , I'm using now Cairo Font , ant it is well written

now the last issue remaining is writing from RIGHT TO LEFT , as If I enter long text , it is added to the left and not to the right